# Get data from mongoDB and print on screen using Angular and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I'm having a small project using MongoDB, Angular and NodeJs.

After register or login successfully, my app will show all information (name, age) about user on screen.

Register and show is done (thanks for @Mikas) but when I login, it only show username, not show age.
Please help me fix it. Thanks you.

My **server.js**

```
// IMPORTS
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./config');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('./user');

// connect database
mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE);

// GLOBAL MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, x-access-token');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// MS API FUNCTIONS
/**
 * Call MS face detection
 * 
 * @param {*} imageData image as dataURL
 * @param {*} onSuccess success callback
 * @param {*} onError error callback
 */
function callMsDetect(imageData, onSuccess, onError) {
    var msDetectOptions = {
        host: config.FACE_API_HOST,
        method: 'POST',
        port: 443,
        path: config.FACE_API_PATH_DETECT,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(imageData),
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': config.FACE_API_KEY
        }
    };

    var msDetectReq = https.request(msDetectOptions, function(msDetectResponse) {
        msDetectResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
        msDetectResponse.on('data', function(msDetectData){
            onSuccess(JSON.parse(msDetectData));
        });
    });

    msDetectReq.on('error', onError);
    msDetectReq.write(imageData);
    msDetectReq.end();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {*} faceId1 face1 to compare
 * @param {*} faceId2 face2 to compare
 * @param {*} onSuccess success callback
 * @param {*} onError error callback
 */
function callMsCompare(faceId1, faceId2, onSuccess, onError) {
    var msVerifyOptions = {
        host: config.FACE_API_HOST,
        method: 'POST',
        port: 443,
        path: config.FACE_API_PATH_VERIFY,
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': config.FACE_API_KEY
        }
    }

    var msVerifyReq = https.request(msVerifyOptions, function(msVerifyResponse) {
        msVerifyResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
        msVerifyResponse.on('data', function(msVerifyData) {
            onSuccess(JSON.parse(msVerifyData));
        });
    })

    msVerifyReq.on('error', onError);
    msVerifyReq.write(JSON.stringify({faceId1: faceId1, faceId2: faceId2}));
    msVerifyReq.end();
}

// PUBLIC API ENDPOINTS

// login endpoint
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    // possible login methods: image or password
    var imageData, 
        password = req.body.password;

    // if neither password nor image is sent, send 400;    
    if(!req.body.password && !req.body.image) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.json({'message': 'Either image or password is required'});
        return;
    }    

    // select user from database    
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }).select('user username faceId password').exec(function(err, user){
        if(err || !user){
            res.statusCode = 403;
            res.json({message:'user not found'});
            return;
        }
        // password login
        if(password) {

            // check password
            var validPassword = user.comparePassword(password);
            if(!validPassword){
                // if password does not match, send 403
                res.statusCode = 403;
                res.json({message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong username / password.'});
            }
            else {
                // if user is found and password is right, create a token
                var token = jwt.sign({
                    username: user.username
                }, config.SECRET);

                // send the token
                res.json({
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token:token
                });
            } 
        }
        else {
            // get image as binary data, so it can be sent to MS
            if(req.body.image) {
                imageData = Buffer.from(req.body.image.split(",")[1], 'base64');
            }
            // image login
            if (imageData) {
                // detect faces on the login image
                callMsDetect(imageData, 
                    function(msDetectData) {
                        // check for the first face
                        // TODO: send error when more than one face is recognized and let the user pick one
                        if(msDetectData[0]){
                            // compare the recognized face to the saved one  
                            callMsCompare(user.faceId, msDetectData[0].faceId, 
                                function(msCompareData){
                                    if(msCompareData.isIdentical && msCompareData.confidence >= config.FACE_API_CONFIDENCE_TRESHOLD){
                                        //if faces match, create a token
                                        var token = jwt.sign({
                                            username: user.username
                                        }, config.SECRET);

                                        //return the information including token as JSON
                                        res.json({
                                            message: 'Login succesful',
                                            token:token
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        // if faces do not match, send 403
                                        res.statusCode = 403;
                                        res.json({'message': 'image login failed - face could not be verified'});
                                    }
                                },
                                function(error){
                                    // if an error occurs during the compare, send 500
                                    res.statusCode = 500;
                                    res.json({'message': 'Failed'});
                                });
                        }
                        else {
                            // if no face can be recognized on the login image, send 400
                            res.statusCode = 400;
                            res.json({'message': 'Failed - No data'});
                        }
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        // if an error occurs during the detection, send 500
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.json({'message':'image login failed - face detection failed'});
                    });
            }
            else {
                // if neither password nor valid image data is given, send error
                res.statusCode = 400;
                res.json({message: 'Either password or image is required'});
            }
        }
    })
});

// register endpoint
app.post('/register', function(req, res){

    // if username or password is missing, send 400
    if(!req.body.user.username || !req.body.user.password) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.json({'message': 'username and password are required'});
        return;
    }

    // create new user object
    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.user.username;
    user.age = req.body.user.age;
    user.password = req.body.user.password;

    // if image is given
    if(req.body.image) {
        // call face detection
        callMsDetect(Buffer.from(req.body.image.split(",")[1], 'base64'),
            function(msDetectData) {
                var faceMessage = '';
                // face will only be saved if only one face is recognized
                // if no face or more than one face is recognized, the user will be informed
                // the account will be created without any faceId anyways
                if(msDetectData.length === 1){
                    user.faceId = msDetectData[0].faceId;
                }
                else if(!msDetectData.length){
                    faceMessage = 'No face was recognized.'
                }
                else {
                    faceMessage = 'More than one face was recognized.'
                }
                user.save(function(error){
                    if(error) {
                        // if an error occurs during save, send 500
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.json({'message':'error during save'});
                        return;
                    }

                    // login user
                    var token = jwt.sign({
                        username: user.username
                    }, config.SECRET);

                    res.json({
                        message: 'User was created. ' + faceMessage,
                        token: token
                    });
                });
            },
            function(error) {
                // if an error occurs during face detection, inform user 
                // the account will be created without any faceId anyways
                user.save(function(error){
                    var faceMessage = 'Face recognition failed';
                    if(error) {
                        // if an error occurs during save, send 500
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.json({message:JSON.stringify(error)});
                        return;
                    }

                    // login user
                    var token = jwt.sign({
                        username: user.username
                    }, config.SECRET);

                    res.json({
                        message: 'User was created. ' + faceMessage,
                        token: token
                    });
                });
            });
    }

    // if no image was sent, just create the account
    else { 
        user.save(function(error){
            if(error) {
                // if an error occurs during save, send 500
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.json({message:'Error during save'});
                return;
            }
            var token = jwt.sign({username: user.username}, config.SECRET);
            res.json({message:'user created',token: token});
        }); 
    }

});

// PRIVATE API ENDPOINTS

// interceptor for private endpoints
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    //check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query['token'] || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    //decode token
    if(token){

        //verifiy secret
        jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET, function(err, decoded){
            if(err){
                return res.status(401).send({
                     message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                });
            } else{
                //if everything is good, save to request for use in other reoutes
                req.user = decoded;
                next();
            }
        })
    } else {
        //if there is no token
        //return an HTTP response of 403 (access forbidden ) and an error message
        return res.status(403).send({
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }

});

// home endpoint: just some test stuff to check that private APIs actually work
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.json({'message': 'As a logged in user, you are allowed to see this content. On this page, you can change your securtity information. You can update your password and your login image.'});
});

// update password endpoint: update users password
app.post('/updatePassword', function(req, res) {

    if(!req.body.oldPassword || !req.body.newPassword) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.json({message: 'old password and new password are required'});
        return;
    }

    // get user from token
    User.findOne({
        username: req.user.username
    }).select('user username faceId password').exec(function(err, user){
        if(err || !user){
            // if no user is found, send 400
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.json({message:'user not found'});
        }
        // if user is found, check for password
        var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.oldPassword);
        if(validPassword){
            // if password is valid, set new password and save
            user.password = req.body.newPassword;
            user.save(function(error){
                if(error) {
                    // if an error ouccurs during save, send 500
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.json({'message':'error during save'});
                }
                res.json({message:'Password changed'});
            });
        }
        else {
            //if password is invalid, send 403
            res.statusCode = 403;
            res.json({message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong old password.'});
        }
    });
});

// udpate image endpoint: update user image
app.post('/updateImage', function(req, res) {

    if(!req.body.image) {
        // if no image was sent, send 400
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.json({message: 'image is required'});
        return;
    }

    // get user from token
    User.findOne({
        username: req.user.username
    }).select('user username faceId').exec(function(error, user){
        if(error || !user){
            // if no user is found, send 400
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.json({message:'user not found'});
            return;
        }
        // call face detection with new face
        callMsDetect(Buffer.from(req.body.image.split(",")[1], 'base64'),
            function(msDetectData) {
                if(msDetectData.length === 1){
                    user.faceId = msDetectData[0].faceId;
                    user.save(function(error){
                        if(error) {
                            // if error occurs during save, send 500
                            res.statusCode = 500;
                            res.json({'message':'error during save'});
                            return;
                        }

                        res.json({
                            message: 'Image was updated.',
                        });
                    });
                }
                // if no face or more than one face was recognized, send 400
                // TODO: give user the opportunity to pick one of them in frontend
                else if(!msDetectData.length){
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.json({message: 'No face was recognized.'})
                }
                else {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.json({message: 'More than one face was recognized.'})
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                // if an error occurs during face detection, send 500
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.json({message: 'image update failed - face recognition error'});
            });

    });
});

// start server
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
})
```

some code of **user.js**

```
//user schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required:true, index: {unique:true}},
    age: {type: String, required:true, index: {unique:true}},
    faceId: {type: String, required:false},
    password: {type: String, required:true, select: false},
});
```

**Login component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { UserRestService } from '../../services/user-rest.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imageUrl;
  username;
  password;
  loginMethod: string = 'camera';

  constructor(private router: Router, private userRestService: UserRestService, private auth: AuthService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  // login method
  login() {
    // set params: password or imageUrl, depending on chosen loginMethod
    var params: any = {
      username: this.username
    };
    if(this.loginMethod === 'password') {
      params.password = this.password;
    }
    else {
      params.image = this.imageUrl;
    }

    // perform http call
    this.userRestService.login( {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
      image: this.imageUrl
    })
      .subscribe( data => {
          // on success set token and user data
          var token = data.token;
          this.auth.setToken(token);
          this.auth.setUser({username: this.username, age: this.age});


          // navigate to home page
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        });
  }



  // image changed handler for embedded components (image picker, camera snapshot)
  imageChanged(data) {
    this.imageUrl = data;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

**I print out by:**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<p>
  {{greeting}} {{user.room}} {{user.age}}      
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You used this `age: this.age` meanwhile `this.age` is undefined

Comment: i tried `this.use.age` but not done

Comment: You can't do that either. You need to create a variable `age` like you did for `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to pass the `user` retrieved from your DB to your response object:

```
res.json({
           message: 'Enjoy your token!',
           token:token,
           user: user
         });
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the `age` property :
`User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, ' user username faceId password age ', function(err, user) { etc. }); ` ?